# error 26 sql express usando entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola estoy empezando a estudiar c# y estoy usando visual studio community 2013 y sql express. Empleo entity framework. Uso el concepto model first para generar las clases y la base de datos. Tengo varias dudas a ver si me pueden ayudar:

1- Muchas veces me aparece el error 26 al conectar a la base de datos. y buscando en la web se resuelve iniciando el servicio nuevamente. Esto quita el error pero me borra todos los datos que habia insertado en bd. Queria saber porque aparece este error , como se soluciona definitivamente y como se evita la perdida de datos.

2- Otra cosa que sucede es que si modifico el modelo desde visual studio tambien se borran los datos de la bd. Esto tiene solucion con esta filosofia model first? o hay que impletementar el concepto code first(el cual no estoy familiarizado)?

Comment: ¿Tienes una clase inicializador heredado de la clase [`DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg679604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: hola Davlio, no lo se , entity genera la base de datos. donde estaria esa clase?

Comment: Podrías realizar una búsqueda general en tu proyecto y encontrar coincidencias, considerando la palabra: `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`.

Comment: busque si aparecio

Comment: System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TContext>

Comment: tipos base  ==>          System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer<in TContext>

Comment: Davlio. es lo q encontre